# Math fonts available for Mac CS4 systems?

Tags: font-recommendation, mac, mathematics

Any leads on the names of serif and sanserif fonts that have comprehensive character sets necessary for advanced math equations and math expressions?

The lead received has been very helpful in clarifying what I need to typeset math, although it looks like I may need to learn how to use a very complicated, specialized font that is much more expensive than the average font family, and would also require knowing a lot more about math than I do. The booklet I am producing is not solid advanced math. It is a description of conference presentations for distribution to teachers and mathematicians, mostly editorial manuscript with equations and expressions lightly scattered throughout, and with occasional heavily mathematical passages.
     For now, I will follow-up on the the suggestions, Lucida, Stix, Euler, Minion math, Cambria and Latin Modern, and create more complex expressions in Photoshop of Illustrator, then embed them into the text. Any other ideas that might streamline the process?

Comment: Only two of the six fonts in question are commercial, the others are free / opensource. My suggestion would be to either learn to use LaTeX or some equation editor, or just re-use the equations from the source manuscripts directly (have the submitters save them as .pdfs w/ embedded fonts)

Answer (score 2):

The (La)TeX community does more math fonts than most, and most of their stuff is freely available (opensource). With the transition to OpenType, platform is pretty much irrelevant:

- Lucida: https://tug.org/store/lucida/opentype.html
- Stix: http://www.stixfonts.com/ --- see also: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/stix/
- Euler: https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf
- Minion Math: http://www.typoma.com/
- Cambria --- this is available from Microsoft and bundled w/ Windows or Office
- Latin Modern (OpenType): http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern